# Axis2-maven dependency failure

Tags: java, maven, wso2, jax-rs

I'm implementing webservice that is connecting to WSO2, so I added some of the required dependencies, namely

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

however, maven exception is thrown:

```
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:SNAPSHOT

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:pom:SNAPSHOT from http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache-ws-snapshots2 has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:pom:SNAPSHOT from/to apache-ws-snapshots2 (http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2): ws.zones.apache.org

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:pom:SNAPSHOT from http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache-ws-snapshots2 has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:pom:SNAPSHOT from/to apache-ws-snapshots2 (http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2): ws.zones.apache.org
```

Now, when i try to open the site, it is not available, so the artifacts cannot be downloaded. Is there a way to change that repo to something else, so I can download it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was hiden in parent POM. More specifically:

```
<groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
<artifactId>axis2-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.6-wso2v1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Apache Axis2 - Parent</name>
```

which lists used repositories, specifically the

```
 http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2
```

like so:

```
<id>apache-ws-snapshots2</id>
<name>Apache ws.zones - 2</name>
<url>http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2</url>

<id>ws-zones</id>
<name>Apache WS Zones Repository</name>
<url>http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2</url>
```

Now, the repository is dead, so when I tried to add the dependency, it failed. The solution to that is to add the correct repository in your settings.xml with the same id. So the record would look like this:

```
    <repository>
      <id>ws-zones</id>
      <name>Maven central repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

This setting will overrite the one in the parent POM (or any POM for that matter) and allows for successful import of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the SNAPSHOT artifacts with the command:

```
-U
```

Example:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:pom:SNAPSHOT from/to apache-ws-snapshots2 (http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2): ws.zones.apache.org: Unknown host ws.zomes.apache.org`

Comment: I tried closing the project, deleting workspace, force updating dependencies, cleaning the rpject, nothing helped.

Comment: @LoneWanderer The error Unknown host ws.zomes.apache.org looks like the repo don't exist or like there aren't connection to ws.zomes.apache.org. Can you check it doing a ping from your machine to Unknown host ws.zomes.apache.org?

Comment: It says that ping request couldn't find it, that confirms that the site is not available..

Comment: @LoneWanderer Yes, the problem is that the host is not available.

Comment: Well yeah, but as stated in original question, is there a way to change the repository?

Comment: @LoneWanderer the plugin org.wso2.carbon.user.core is using an SNAPSHOT version and this is not recomendable because many companies delete SNAPSHOT version after x months. The unique way is to download this version from another source and upload it to your artifact repository(nexus, artifactory...) or to update your org.wso2.carbon.user.core to try to use another version of org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar